# How to add a custom keyword to be treated as "class" in clang format?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I would like to use `clang-format` to format **specc code** (`<file>.sc`)

[Specc](http://www.cecs.uci.edu/%7Especc/SpecC_LRM_10.pdf) has some predefined keywords that could be formatted the same way a `class` is formatted in C++:

- `behavior`
- `interface`

Can I make this happen in the `.clang-format` file?

Input file with the `behavior` keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>

behavior Main(void)
{
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        return(0);
    }
};
```

Output of `clang-format -style=Mozilla hello.sc`

```
#include <stdio.h>

behavior Main(void) 
{
    int main(void) 
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        return (0);
    }
}
;
```

If I were using the keyword `class` instead of `behavior`, this is the output I get, which is what I want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Main(void) 
{
    int main(void) 
    {
      printf("Hello World!\n");
      return (0);
    }
};
```

TLDR:
I would like `clang-format` to handle the keyword `behavior`, from **specc**, as it handles the keyword `class`.

Note, I just want to **format** the file. I am not planning to compile it with a C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you elaborate a little more on how to use `MACRO`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner, the language SpecC is a superset of C, `behavior` is a keyword that is understood by the specc compiler. I would like to clang-format to treat the keyword `behavior` as it treats the keyword `class`.

Comment: So what you want is that clang sees "behaviour" and understands "class". I.e. you do not actually want any functional difference, any meaning difference, just be allowed to write "behaviour" and mean "class" ?

Comment: Could you decribe the difference between `class` and `behaviour` from point of view of specc? I ask because I am pretty sure that it is exactly the part which will disappoint you after using the solution proposed by @Jarod42 and me.

Comment: You can write a short script around `clang-format` that calls `sed` before and after to swap `behavior` for `class` (vice versa).

Comment: I proposed to pass `-Dbehavior=class` (as `#define behavior class`) in command line.

Comment: Following up this question: I.e. you do not actually want any functional difference, any meaning difference, just be allowed to write "behavior" and mean "class" ? --- Correct all I want is to clang-format to treat the keyword behavior as a keyword class. Is it possible to do it in the `.clang-format` file?

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 for the idea, but the -D does not work as a clang-format input argument. @Jason `sed` worked like a charm, did not think of it before. Thanks

Comment: But to be clear, your desired output `class Main(void)` is not legal c++. The extra argument `(void)` is not in the c++ syntax, so to get rid of that, or change it to something interesting like a template will require `sed`. That said, you could also fix this by having the sed preprocess declare a macro called Main which in turn declares a class called Main, but I think you will find this more restrictive than practical.

Comment: @GemTaylor fair enough, but It is ok if clang-format fails to format something as long as it covers most of my use cases. it does happen that what comes after `class Main(void)` still gets properly formatted :)

Comment: OK. I hadn't really realised you were not trying to compile it at all just pretty-print it. I am also concerned that your `sed`ing might inadvertently change some other instance of the word `class` or `behaviour` in a comment or a variable name. It might be better to change `behaviour` to `class /*AS behaviour*/` and then only change back  `class /*AS behaviour*/` to `behaviour`

Comment: For example, what if you had the `behaviour class(Void) {`

Comment: Valid suggestions! Thanks. Because specc code is a superset  of C code (not C++), I will not be using the keyword class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered developing/contributing SpecC support into clang-format as a first-class language?

As its mainly a C-style language I wouldn't think it would be that hard to add.

I recently began an effort to add C# support (which I'd guess is probably worse), and faced similar issues around formatting where I wanted keywords to behave differently in C# to C++ (public being one of them)

As an example, one mechanism is to transform keywords into other keyword types (or Token types), which can then be used later to format the code differently for different languages.

In this example, I'm transforming the "behavior" tokens into thinking they are "class"

```
bool FormatTokenLexer::tryMergeSpeccCBehavior() {
  if (Tokens.size() < 1)
    return false;
  auto &Identifier = *(Tokens.end() - 1);
  if (!Identifier->is(tok::identifier))
    return false;

  if ((Identifier->TokenText == "behavior"))
    Identifier->Tok.setKind(tok::kw_class);
  return true;
}
```

Whilst I couldn't get your exact example to work the (the Main(void)) seemed to be confusing clang-format

With just this change (and calling it during Lexing), I was able to make clang-format think that the "behavior" keyword was the "class" keyword and not just a return type (which is what I think it thinks it is)

This means when it sees behaviour it would apply any of the formatting rules that were looking for a class, and this would have a tendency to do more of the correct thing.

You'd need a little more plumbing to allow for some SpecC specific rules but it wouldn't be beyond the bounds of possibilities.

```
$ clang-format -style=Mozilla hello.sc
#include <stdio.h>

behavior Main
{
  int main(void)
  {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return (0);
  }
};

behavior B(in int p1, out int p2)
{

  int a, b;

  int f(int x) { return (x * x); }

  void main(void)
  {
    a = p1;
    b = f(a);
    p2 = b;
  }
};
```

LLVM has a pretty high bar about what they let in, but I'd guess if this was a standard language and there was significant interest and someone was willing to support it you could at least ask them to consider it (especially if someone supplied the patches), or you could always "simply fork LLVM" and add it.

Just a thought

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping you could do  something similar in the config file, but this is the answer I was trying to find. I will consider extending it as I find more format problems that bother me.

Comment: Do you know what all else needs to be added to new keywords in Clang? I'm getting errors about the keyword being an undefined function, after adding it to `TokenKinds.td`, and `Attr.td`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jason in a comment to my question, I can use `sed` to replace the keywords. Thus what I ended up doing was wrapping the following command in a shell script:

```
sed "s/behavior/class/g" <file>.sc | clang-format -style=Mozilla | sed "s/class/behavior/g" > <file>.sc
```

Comment: Overwriting the same file you're reading from is not safe. Best practice is to write to a temporary file and then `mv` the copy over top the original when finished.